# putting observations in one variable SAS EG

Tags: sas

I have some data set, for ex.

```
card1    stick2
card3    stick2
card1    stick1
card4    stick1
```

I need to get a new variable with the resul:(final outdata)

```
                       new_variable
  card1    stick2      card1,card3 
  card3    stick2      card1,card3
  card1    stick1      card1,card4
  card4    stick1      card1,card4
```

I need to collect all cards observations which have every stick in a new_variable

Comment: It helps if you explicitly state the rule to create the variable. Trying to figure it from data out is tedious at best.  Please also post what you've tried to adhere to SO rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the `catx` function

```
new_variable = catx(',',var1,var2);
```

From SAS help:
CATX Function - Removes leading and trailing blanks, inserts delimiters, and returns a concatenated character string.

[EDIT]

You will need to sort by stick, process in a Data Step, and merge back the results.

```
proc sort data=have;
by stick;
run;

data new_var;
set have;
by stick;

format new_variable $200.;
retain new_variable;

if first.stick then
   new_variable = "";

new_variable = catx(",",new_variable,card);

if last.stick then 
   output;
run;

data want;
merge have new_var(keep=stick new_variable);
by stick;
run;
```

Comment: the observations in different rows as you can see, it won t work

Comment: Then please edit your question with more explanation as to the logic you are attempting.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, I need to collect all cards observations  which have every stick in a new_variable